# jsf regex any letter character, multiple letters

Tags: regex, jsf, unicode

I want to validate a 'name' field in jsf. I need to write a regex to allow any character (unicode), but no numbers or special symbols.
I found that

> \p{L}  matches a single code point in the category "letter".

But it doesn't work. Plus, how did I rewrite it to match an array of chars?

Cheers.

Comment: with a little help from my friends.. [REGExr](http://www.regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `+` modifier just after:

```
\p{L}+
```

That means one or more letters.

Comment: Tried it already and it doesn't work .. accepts only one char

Comment: @Steffi: Really? I'm surprised. Please, edit your question and add a piece of code.